# Very Mysterious/Random C++ WDK STL 7 Error: iosfwd(202): error C2144: syntax error

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, stl, wdk

I have the following trivial file named `Temp.cpp`:

```
#include <string>
int main() { return 0; }
```

and I'm trying to compile it with the following command-line in the Windows XP Free Build Environment, using WDK 7.1:

```
cl.exe /Iinc\api\crt\stl70 /Iinc\crt C:\Temp.cpp
```

and I'm getting really random errors like:

```
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.30729.207 for 80x86

C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api\crt\stl70\iosfwd(202) :
    error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'
```

The error goes away if I use `stl60` instead of `stl70`, but that doesn't solve the problem.

What's the cause of the problem?

---

**Update:** I tried uninstalling and installing the WDK again, but nothing changed. :(

---

**Update 2:** Okay, apparently the error is screaming out at the header file itself: `_SCL_INSECURE_DEPRECATE` is the cause. Does anybody know how to turn it off *correctly*? (If I just comment out the lines, I get a ton more errors regarding a bunch of other macros.)

Comment: Funny, I tried searching `WDK stl70 errors` and guess what popped up as first place in google.. that damn thing gets faster every day. o_O

Comment: @Xeo: Loll yeah it's pretty beast :)

Comment: VC 7.0 is one of the worst compilers ever.  :-(  Current version is 10.0 SP1.

Comment: not sure what the actual problem is, but don't you have to have `return` in `main`?

Comment: @Andrey: Yes, but that has nothing to do with this lol. I changed it for you though. :P

Comment: @Andrey: you don't need to have `return` in `main()` in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself, through modifying the headers and guess'n'checking:

I need to have `_STL70_` defined.

Answer (score 0):

Which `cl.exe` are you picking up? If your path happens to have an older (VC6) compiler before the WDK one, you'd expect these errors. VC6 can't compile the STL as shipped with VC7

Comment: No, it's the correct one. I used the start-menu entry (Windows Driver Kits->Build Environments->Windows XP->etc.) and I'm 100% sure it's the correct compiler/linker. I don't even have VC6 installed, haha.

Comment: The VC6 compiler shipped with older WDK's, too.

Comment: Nope; Process Monitor is telling me I'm opening the correct compilers, files, and everything. (My PATH doesn't have any compilers in it either.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: just so everyone knows exactly what compiler is being dealt with, paste into the question the logo/banner line the compiler prints out as the first line of output.

Answer (score 0):

> apparently the error is screaming out at the header file itself: `_SCL_INSECURE_DEPRECATE` is the cause. Does anybody know how to turn it off correctly?

If you're having problems with `_SCL_INSECURE_DEPRECATE`, try setting:

```
/D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
```

But given the error message you're seeing it sounds like you're the compiling headers with a a compiler that's older than the headers support (so this might not get you very far anyway).

Comment: Yup, already tried that. No, it didn't help, though thanks. :\ And no, I'm using completely the correct compiler, I even reinstalled it. I'm convinced the problem is definitely not of that kind; it's just an issue with the flags/macros.